# StatFs throws Invalid path: /storage/sdcard0/Download

Tags: android, android-file

There is a method that return available space for some directory:

```
fun bytesAvailable(f: File): Long {
    val stat = StatFs(f.path)
    val bytesAvailable = stat.blockSize.toLong() * stat.availableBlocks.toLong()
    return bytesAvailable
}
```

And there is how I use it:

```
val downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
bytesAvailable(backupFile)
```

I can't catch this bug directly on my phone, but I see such crash reports from users:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/sdcard0/Download
android.os.StatFs.doStat (StatFs.java:46)
android.os.StatFs.<init> (StatFs.java:39)
com.nickapps.Diary.presentation.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsPresenter.bytesAvailable (SettingsPresenter.kt:187)
com.nickapps.Diary.presentation.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsPresenter$doSimpleExport$2.call (SettingsPresenter.kt:74)
com.nickapps.Diary.presentation.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsPresenter$doSimpleExport$2.call (SettingsPresenter.kt:26)
rx.internal.operators.CompletableFlatMapSingleToCompletable$SourceSubscriber.onSuccess (CompletableFlatMapSingleToCompletable.java:61)
rx.Single$18.onNext (Single.java:1896)
...


Caused by android.system.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
libcore.io.Posix.statvfs (Posix.java)
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.statvfs (BlockGuardOs.java:298)
android.system.Os.statvfs (Os.java:459)
android.os.StatFs.doStat (StatFs.java:44)
android.os.StatFs.<init> (StatFs.java:39)
com.nickapps.Diary.presentation.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsPresenter.bytesAvailable (SettingsPresenter.kt:187)
com.nickapps.Diary.presentation.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsPresenter$doSimpleExport$2.call (SettingsPresenter.kt:74)
com.nickapps.Diary.presentation.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsPresenter$doSimpleExport$2.call (SettingsPresenter.kt:26)
```

Such exception throws only on 21+ devices. Runtime permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted.

Is it a bug? Can the `Download` folder does not exist on some devices?

Comment: "Can the Download folder does not exist on some devices?" -- sure. Check to see if the directory exists first.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it okay to call `mkdir()` if it doesn't exist?

Comment: It should be. We used to have to do that to support the Android SDK emulator, as it used to not ship with standard directories created.